# Image link not to download the image

Tags: html, twitter, hyperlink

How to make an image link not to download the image but to show it on the browser? If you go to twitter and click on a user's photo it will redirect you to the photo and it seems to be a simple link.

In my case-Google Chrome and firefox are downloading the image. Is this has to do with the IIS or just the browsers?

Any ideas?

Example:

```
<a href="http://photos.wadja.com/845_763686_t.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://photos.wadja.com/845_763686_t.jpg" id="profile_pic" width="72" height="72" class="cursor"></a>
```

Comment: Accept some answers, and people will be more likely to help you.

Comment: (and post the code you're currently using that doesn't work like you'd like it to)

Comment: How are you linking to the image? Full URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forced downloads are caused by HTTP response codes.
for example if you have [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header set it will force download.

You have to check the settings in your IIS.